# Update error 80050007 windows defender updates 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update, windows-error-reporting

I've read several posts offering solutions but none seem to help. I have Comodo installed - defender I think gets disabled by this. Tried running update as administrator and a script. Made sure logged in as administrator. Disabled my firewall. I get the error code at the end of trying to install, following download.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my own problem. Solution was remove third party anti virus security and firewall. In this case comodo suite. Then windows defender becomes accessible again ( buttons wouldn't respond) turn off app by unchecking box - first though run windows update which should now complete . Now when try to access get message box pops up to disabled and won't launch. Now run the install Comodo. Restart windows. Sorted. Seems a conflict. Should have been properly disable. Software tries to do this i think

Comment: You cannot have 2 antivirus softwares operating at the same time, they butt heads as you have found out.